# Tabbed menu animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to follow the material design theme, although I'm not using polymer.

I want to create a tabbed menu and to animate it similar to how it is specified in the design guides.

I don't want to recreate the ripple effect, just the animated bar at the bottom of the tab that moves when a tab is focused on.

You can see an example here (the animation is at the the very bottom of the page)
[Tab touch target animation](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html)

I'm not sure if this could be done just using CSS, but if it can't jquery/js isn't an issue.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** *I don't like that you have put very little effort into this question, you have not shown any attempts at it yourself but I had a look and liked the tabbed menu so much I wanted to create it for my Codepen account.*

So I may as well answer this question, I have commented my code so you can work through it and see what everything is doing. Its just a matter of `position: absolute` the slider and then moving it to the selected tabs location using the width of the tabs to set its position.

```js
$("ul li").click(function(e) {

  /* Add the slider movement */

  // what tab was pressed
  var whatTab = $(this).index();

  // Work out how far the slider needs to go
  var howFar = 160 * whatTab;

  $(".slider").css({
    left: howFar + "px"
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700);
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background: #222;
}
ul {
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 480px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #39CCCC;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background: yellow;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two</li>
  <li>Item Three</li>
  <li class="slider"></li>
</ul>
```

See [**here**](http://codepen.io/Ruddy/pen/eNpXQz/) for the ripple effect on the menu too, code snippets don't like them for some reason.

Comment: Apologies for what seems like a lack of effort - I've actually spent some considerable time trying to find the solution on Google, however not knowing how to phrase my queries has probably been the problem. Thanks for your efforts - its very much appreciated.

Comment: By the way, I just have to say that this is awesome!

Comment: Having read through your documentation, I now have a better understanding. Quick question - how can this be made responsive - in other words get the x co-ordinate of the tab rather than use a fixed width formula?

Comment: In the jQuery you could get the width of the tabs so you don't have to hardcode it in. Is that what you mean or are you more leaning towards the tabs being all different sizes?

Comment: Well there's a couple of instances where this would be handy. Material guidlines stiplulate only a min/max width, so its entirely possible that tabs could be of different sizes. The second scenario would be responsiveness - my phone is 360 px wide, yours is 320px... you get the picture.

Comment: @JohnOhara I will work on this a bit later. I don't think it will be that hard to do. Will update you when I attempt it.

Comment: Cheers ruddu you're a star - I'm sure this is something many people will want.

Comment: @JohnOhara It's definitely something people like - [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Ruddy/details/eNpXQz/)